How do I convert a rlang::call2 to character?
How do I convert the following call to a character?
library(rlang)
call2("element_text", list(color = "red", size = 12))

The expected result should be a string of length 1:
element_text(list(color = "red", size = 12))

I tried using deparse, rlang::as_label and capture.output but they all return:
element_text(list(color = \"red\", size = 12))

Notice the unexpected \"red\"

The linked duplicate uses deparse(). If you want to stick with rlang you could also use as_label().

@samR the thing is with as_labl, deparse and capture.output that they all backslash "red" for some reason.

This is just how R is printing the string because it contains double-quotes. If you do print(call2("element_text", list(color = "red", size = 12)), quote=FALSE) you'll see it doesn't actually have a backslash in it.
